# Has any animal ever had a rotating part?

Tags: evolution, zoology, anatomy

Outside of microscopic structures (I'm thinking of a flagellum, which I *think* is a true motor) has any animal evolved a part that continually rotates compared to the rest of its body?

Comment: A more universal microscopic example is the ATP synthase in mitochondria. The flagellum example only applies to bacterial flagella. Can't help on macroscopic examples.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_locomotion_in_living_systems): there's a reasonably well-written popular discussion of why the evolution of such a body part is very difficult to imagine. However the page does mention [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_(zoology)) as the single known macroscopic example (a rod rotated by cilia).

Comment: Not a 360 degree rotation but Owls can rotate their heads by 270 degrees without any serous damage.

Comment: Duplicate http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7932/why-are-there-no-wheeled-animals

Comment: @HuguesFontenelle Not really a dupe, admitedly, if there were animals with wheels then that would answer this question but the lact of animals with wheels doesn't mean the lack of _any_ rotational body part.

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh Thanks, I had considered that though.  The thing is it can rotate, it is a _wind_ then _unwind_ mechanism where the rotation creates increasing torque.